# Raspberry Pi 4 model B not booting, no Act light - hardware fault diagnose help

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues, activity-led, act

I have purchased a preowned (due to supply shortage) Raspberry Pi 4 Model B 2Gb RAM variant. To my disappointment it is not booting up.

The green ACT light blinks once very quickly, on connecting the power supply. The red light lights up and remains solid. However there is no subsequent ACT light and no boot.

I have tried with mupliple SD cards and power supplies (which work for other raspberry pis that I have). I have tried with Raspberry Pi OS and Ubuntu 22.04 server, both 32 bits and 64 bits.

The SD card slot does not look damaged. I even tried booting from the USB port but it did not work. There is no power on the USB ports too.

Any help in diagnosing the problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: Pi4 boot sticky https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151#p1485558

Comment: Do you get the boot diagnostics screen if you just connect power and screen, no sd card?

Comment: @CoderMike No, the screen says no signal, so I assume nothing it getting output from the HDMI. I tried with HDMI0.

Comment: Sounds like the Pi is faulty.

Comment: I have a faulty pi4 as well. No image on screen with or without sdcard. I found this schematic: https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi4/raspberry-pi-4-reduced-schematics.pdf. On the right side is the power controller and it lists some test points, TP4, TP11, TP13, TP14 and what voltage is expected at these points. On my pi they voltage was either too low or 0, so I expect the power controller to be dead on mine. You can try the same if you have a voltmeter.